# Push notifications will work after Parse migration?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, migration, push

I just migrated the Parse DB to my own Server, but haven't finalized the process yet.
I haven't migrate my push notification delivery service to a new one.

My question is:

Should I migrate the Push notification to another service, or will still work?

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: WIll not work :(